# Firebase listener doesn't trigger when collection size is too big

Tags: c#, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

```
_firestoreDb.Collection(collectionPath).Listen(callback);
```

When I listen to a collection that contains a few (hundreds) documents, the listener works fine. However, when the collection starts getting bulky (over 30-40k), it never triggers the callback. Neither the 'initial call' nor when a creation/deletion happens.

`CollectionGroup` seems to have the same behavior.

Is there any size limit on query listeners? I haven't found any mention on Firebase documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I listen to a collection that contains a few (hundreds) documents, the listener works fine.

That's the expected behavior.

> However when the collection starts getting bulky (over 30-40k), it never triggers the callback.

That's also the expected behavior since reading that amount of data takes a long long time. Besides that, it's also very costly, since everything in Firestore it's about the number of [reads and writes you perform](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing).

Reading 30-40k documents at once can be considered an enormous amount of data. Besides that, I don't think that somebody will ever be interested in reading all that data. So the best option that you have is to [limit the number of documents your read](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data).

Besides that, the most common approach would be to always read the exact number of documents that you display on the screen. That being said, you should consider getting data in smaller chunks. Most likely 10-20 documents. You can also consider implementing [pagination](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors) if your app's use case requires it.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. In my question I didn't mention the goal, which is not to display any data but to use the snapshot initial call to initialize a collection counter. I will try a different approach.

Comment: Yep. If you need a counter, then I think that this [article](How to count the number of documents in a Firestore collection?) will help. Give it a try and tell me if ti works.

Comment: While your answer explains very clearly the reasons of the behavior, I expect to know the exact size above which the callback is not triggered. Let me wait for other users' contributions before clicking the green tick

Comment: Fair enough, but please note that it's not a fixed number of documents, since the size of the documents may vary.